# Remove all punctuation from text including apostrophes for tm package

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I have a of vector consisting of Tweets (just the message text) that I am cleaning for text mining purposes. I have used `removePunctuation` from the `tm` package like so:

```
clean_tweet_text = removePunctuation(tweet_text)
```

This have resulted in a vector with all punctuation removed from the text *except* apostrophes, which ruins my keyword searches because words touching apostrophes are not registered. For example, one of my keywords is `climate` but if a tweet has `'climate` it won't be counted.

How can I removes all the apostrophes/single quotes from my vector?

Here is the header from `dput` for a reproducible example:

```
c("expert briefing on climatechange disarmament sdgs nmun httpstco5gqkngpkap", 
"who uses nasa earth science data he looks at impact of aerosols on climateamp weather httpstcof4azsiqkw1 https…", 
"rt oddly enough some republicans think climate change is real oddly enough… httpstcomtlfx1mnuf uniteblue https…", 
"better dead than red bill gates says that only socialism can save us from climate change httpstcopypqmd1fok", 
"i see red people bill gates says that only socialism can save us from climate change httpstcopypqmd1fok", 
"why go for ecosystem basses conservation climatechange raajje maldives ecocaremv httpstcorauhjbasyl", 
"ted cruz ‘climate change is not science it’s religion’ httpstco0qqtbofe0h via glennbeck", 
"unusual warming kills gulf of maine cod  discovery news globalwarming  httpstco39uvock3xe", 
"this is an amusing headline bill gates says that only socialism can save us from climate change httpstcobfs5zbcijc", 
"what do the remaining republican candidates have to say about climate change fixgov httpstcoxpszwbrcnh httpstcodgqyidkw6o"
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove all punctuation (including apostrophes and single quotes), you can just use `gsub()`:

```r
x <- c("expert briefing on climatechange disarmament sdgs nmun httpstco5gqkngpkap",
       "who uses nasa earth science data he looks at impact of aerosols on climateamp weather httpstcof4azsiqkw1 https…",
       "rt oddly enough some republicans think climate change is real oddly enough… httpstcomtlfx1mnuf uniteblue https…",
       "better dead than red bill gates says that only socialism can save us from climate change httpstcopypqmd1fok",
       "i see red people bill gates says that only socialism can save us from climate change httpstcopypqmd1fok",
       "why go for ecosystem basses conservation climatechange raajje maldives ecocaremv httpstcorauhjbasyl",
       "ted cruz ‘climate change is not science it’s religion’ httpstco0qqtbofe0h via glennbeck",
       "unusual warming kills gulf of maine cod discovery news globalwarming httpstco39uvock3xe",
       "this is an amusing headline bill gates says that only socialism can save us from climate change httpstcobfs5zbcijc",
       "what do the remaining republican candidates have to say about climate change fixgov httpstcoxpszwbrcnh httpstcodgqyidkw6o")

gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x)
#>  [1] "expert briefing on climatechange disarmament sdgs nmun httpstco5gqkngpkap"                                                
#>  [2] "who uses nasa earth science data he looks at impact of aerosols on climateamp weather httpstcof4azsiqkw1 https"           
#>  [3] "rt oddly enough some republicans think climate change is real oddly enough httpstcomtlfx1mnuf uniteblue https"            
#>  [4] "better dead than red bill gates says that only socialism can save us from climate change httpstcopypqmd1fok"              
#>  [5] "i see red people bill gates says that only socialism can save us from climate change httpstcopypqmd1fok"                  
#>  [6] "why go for ecosystem basses conservation climatechange raajje maldives ecocaremv httpstcorauhjbasyl"                      
#>  [7] "ted cruz climate change is not science its religion httpstco0qqtbofe0h via glennbeck"                                     
#>  [8] "unusual warming kills gulf of maine cod discovery news globalwarming httpstco39uvock3xe"                                  
#>  [9] "this is an amusing headline bill gates says that only socialism can save us from climate change httpstcobfs5zbcijc"       
#> [10] "what do the remaining republican candidates have to say about climate change fixgov httpstcoxpszwbrcnh httpstcodgqyidkw6o"
```

`gsub()` replaces all occurrences of its first argument in its third argument with its second argument (see `help("gsub")`). Here, that means it replaces all occurrences in our vector `x` of any of the characters in the set `[[:punct:]]` with `""` (remove them).

What characters does that remove? From `help("regex")`:

> [:punct:]
>
> Punctuation characters:
>       ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~.

#### Update

It appears this occurs because your apostrophes are like `‘` instead of like `'`. So, if you want to stick with `tm::removePunctuation()`, you can also use

```r
tm::removePunctuation(x, ucp = TRUE)
#>  [1] "expert briefing on climatechange disarmament sdgs nmun httpstco5gqkngpkap"                                                
#>  [2] "who uses nasa earth science data he looks at impact of aerosols on climateamp weather httpstcof4azsiqkw1 https"           
#>  [3] "rt oddly enough some republicans think climate change is real oddly enough httpstcomtlfx1mnuf uniteblue https"            
#>  [4] "better dead than red bill gates says that only socialism can save us from climate change httpstcopypqmd1fok"              
#>  [5] "i see red people bill gates says that only socialism can save us from climate change httpstcopypqmd1fok"                  
#>  [6] "why go for ecosystem basses conservation climatechange raajje maldives ecocaremv httpstcorauhjbasyl"                      
#>  [7] "ted cruz climate change is not science its religion httpstco0qqtbofe0h via glennbeck"                                     
#>  [8] "unusual warming kills gulf of maine cod discovery news globalwarming httpstco39uvock3xe"                                  
#>  [9] "this is an amusing headline bill gates says that only socialism can save us from climate change httpstcobfs5zbcijc"       
#> [10] "what do the remaining republican candidates have to say about climate change fixgov httpstcoxpszwbrcnh httpstcodgqyidkw6o"
```

Comment: I'll note (for the OP) that `ucp = TRUE` pretty much just uses the `gsub` method you provided only without the good use of a POSIX regular expression. This is what it does: `gsub("\\p{P}+", "", x, perl = TRUE)`. The vastly more readable `[[:punct:]]` == `\p{P}`