# tm::removePunctuation doesn't remove all punctuation in R?

Tags: r, string, nlp

I have 900K `strings` in one `column` of one `dataframe`.

I am trying to clean them and one of the cleaning methods I use is `removePunctuation` from the `tm` package in R.

Please guide me why the following punctuation doesn't get removed:

```
> removePunctuation("grillin’")
[1] "grillin’"
> removePunctuation("’ eggs benedict day")
[1] "’ eggs benedict day"
```

Comment: @akrun I am aware of this I am wondering why the function doesn't do this...

Comment: I see 3 reopen requests.  Not sure if the people who have looked at the dupe didn't see the update in duckmayr' answer `tm::removePunctuation(x, ucp = TRUE)`

Comment: Note that (in case it gets reopened,) the link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392785/remove-all-punctuation-from-text-including-apostrophes-for-tm-package  Anybody can check the same answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` from `base R`

```
sub("’", "", "grillin’") 
#[1] "grillin"
```

---

If we look at `?removePunctuation`, by default, some of the categories are `FALSE`, i.e. `ucp`

> removePunctuation(x,
>                     preserve_intra_word_contractions = FALSE,
>                     preserve_intra_word_dashes = FALSE,
>                     ucp = FALSE, ...)

In the documentation for `ucp`, it says

> ucp -  If FALSE (default), characters in the ASCII [:punct:] class are taken; if TRUE, the characters with Unicode general category P (Punctuation).

So, if the default option for `ucp = FALSE` is changed to `TRUE`, then it should work.  Regarding whether the character is an ASCII or not, we can check with `grep`

The character showed is not `ASCII`

```
grep("[[:ascii:]]", "’", perl = TRUE )
#integer(0)
grep("[[:ascii:]]", "'", perl = TRUE)
#[1] 1
```

---

If the OP is using `tm` for quantitative text analysis, according to [here](https://quanteda.io/articles/pkgdown/comparison.html), `quanteda` may have more features.

If we check the `Usage` of `?dfm` (from `quanteda`), most of the the cleaning happens automatically as they are all by default `TRUE`

> dfm(x, verbose = TRUE, toLower = TRUE,
>     removeNumbers = TRUE, removePunct = TRUE, removeSeparators = TRUE,
>     removeTwitter = FALSE, stem = FALSE, ignoredFeatures = NULL,
>     keptFeatures = NULL, language = "english", thesaurus = NULL,
>     dictionary = NULL, valuetype = c("glob", "regex", "fixed"), ...)

Comment: It looks like it's a curved "smart" quote, not a straight quote like you have in your `sub` call

Answer (score 3):

It works with `ucp = TRUE`

```
tm::removePunctuation("grillin’", ucp = TRUE)
```

From `?removePunctuation`

> ucp
>   a logical specifying whether to use Unicode character properties for determining punctuation characters. If FALSE (default), characters in the ASCII [:punct:] class are taken; if TRUE, the characters with Unicode general category P (Punctuation).

So I am assuming `’` comes under Unicode general category P.

Comment: can you explain a bit more about the unicode general category P?

Comment: @SteveS Sorry, I am not aware either but quick search lead me to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:General_Category_(Unicode)) document. Maybe it is helpful.

Comment: @SteveS Also, `’` is not a part of [ASCII punctuations](https://www.kerryr.net/pioneers/ascii3.htm) so it does not get replaced with `ucp = FALSE`